# Show that the space of the harmonic functions over $\Omega$ in $L^2$ are closed.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a open set and $H(\Omega)$ the space of the harmonic functions over $\Omega$ that are in $L^2(\Omega)$. Show that $H(\Omega)$ is a closed subset of $L^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $H(\Omega)$ are the elements $u\in\mathbb L^2(\Omega)$ which satisfy the equation 
$$\int_{\Omega}u(x)\Delta \varphi(x)\mathrm dx=0$$
for any $\varphi$ smooth with compact support. 
It's the orthogonal of the subspace $V:=\{\Delta \varphi,\varphi\mbox{ smooth with compact support}\}$.

Comment: Aren't you including nondifferentiable functions though? Not every $L^2$ function satisfying this will be harmonic in the classical sense.

Comment: I interpreted "harmonic" has "harmonic" in the weak sense: their weak Laplacian is $0$.